# new wp_query pagination gives 404

Tags: wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I've finally exhausted my patience trawling google trying to find a solution to this... any help VERY MUCH appreciated.

I've got a site set up on WP 3.3.2 and I'm using wp_query to query a custom post type:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'feedback',
    'meta_key' => 'Overall how would you grade this course?',
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'paged' => $paged
    );

$feedback  = new WP_Query($args);
```

I've got some additional meta queries in there as well but that's the crux of it.

My problem is pagination... my url comes out as domain.com/client-feedback/page/2/ but I get a 404.

So far I've tried getting the $paged variable as shown above, and also extracting the page number from the URL. I'm fairly confident I've got this nailed. If I force `'paged' => 2` I get the second page of results no problem.

I've also tried running the query as shown, but also hijacking $wp_query (dumping the original into a $temp variable and restoring it after I'm done.)

No matter what I try I can't get beyond page 1. I've been using the pagenavi plugin for ease but disabling it makes no difference.

My best guess is it's permalink related - I've tried /%category%/%postname/ and just /%postname%/ but that makes no difference either.

I'm at a dead end with this one - any thoughts / insight / condolences greatly appreciated.

David.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried setting the number of posts per page in the wordpress Settings -> Reading?

Answer (score 1):

I gave an plural slug to my custom post type and added this function bellow to solve the problem.

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'department_listing_disable_redirect_canonical' );

function department_listing_disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ) 
{

    if ( is_singular( 'your_custom_post_type_SLUG' ) )
        $redirect_url = false;

    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Hope it helps =D